# How to create Hinge loss function in python from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, loss-functions, hinge-loss

I am learning the math behind popular loss functions by trying to hard code all loss functions from scratch. I tried to code hinge loss

My code

```py
def hinge_fun(actual, predicted):
    # replacing 0 = -1
    new_predicted = np.array([-1 if i==0 else i for i in predicted])
    
    # calculating hinge loss
    hinge_loss = np.mean([max(0, 1-x*y) for x, y in zip(actual, new_predicted)])
    return hinge_loss

hinge_fun(actual, predicted)
```

I converted all 0's to -1 because I read [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/detailed-guide-7-loss-functions-machine-learning-python-code/) that hinge loss expects target values as [-1, 1]

Now my real question here is that when I tested my function with sklearn's hinge loss function, it is not always the same. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import hinge_loss

# case 1
actual = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
predicted = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])

hinge_loss(actual, predicted) # sklearn function output 0.7
hinge_fun(actual, predicted) # my function output 0.7

# case 2
actual = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
predicted = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

hinge_loss(actual, predicted) # sklearn function output 0.8333333333333334
hinge_fun(actual, predicted) # my function output 0.9166666666666666
```

Can you see the difference in the second case, I just showed two cases but the output is not always the same. I don't know what I am missing in my function, can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for your code, besides changing `predicted` to `new_predicted`. You forgot to change the label for `actual` from $0$ to $-1$.

Also, when we use the sklean `hinge_loss` function, the prediction value can actually be a float, hence the function is not aware that you intend to map $0$ to $-1$. To achieve the same result, you should pass `new_predicted` to the sklearn function.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import hinge_loss

def hinge_fun(actual, predicted):
    # replacing 0 = -1
    new_predicted = predicted - (predicted == 0)
    new_actual = actual - (actual == 0)

    # calculating hinge loss
    hinge_loss = np.mean([max(0, 1-x*y) for x, y in zip(new_actual, new_predicted)])
    return hinge_loss


# case 1
actual = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
predicted = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
new_predicted = predicted - (predicted == 0)
print(hinge_loss(actual, new_predicted)) # sklearn function output 0.4
print(hinge_fun(actual, predicted)) # my function output 0.4

# case 2
actual = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
predicted = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
new_predicted = predicted - (predicted == 0)
print(hinge_loss(actual, new_predicted)) # sklearn function output 0.5
print(hinge_fun(actual, predicted)) # my function output 0.5
```